# Migrating passwords from web2py to Django

Tags: django, passwords, web2py, sha512

I have passwords stored in web2py using SHA 512 algorithm. I am now migrating the models to django and hence need a way to hash passwords in django using SHA 512 in the same way as web2py does so that I can authenticate the old users with the same passwords.Please suggest some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/tLAiqRaXG48) a Python snippet to recreate the convention used in web2py would be the following:

```
from hashlib import md5
import hmac
hmac_key = '<your secret key>'
password = 'insecure'
thehash = hmac.new(hmac_key, password).hexdigest()
print thehash
```

web2py uses hmac (which is your secret + the plaintext of the user's password) as the final hash and not just a straight MD5/SHA hash (depending on your settings).  So you would just need to swap out MD5 for SHA in the above example to get things working on your end.  But this implementation is all you would need to implement in your new application to make them cross compatible as long as the secret key is the same.

According to the [docs](http://app3.sharpfreight.com/examples/static/epydoc/web2py.gluon.validators.CRYPT-class.html) the hash is stored in the following format:

```
    <algorithm>$<salt>$<hash>
```

so if there is a salt used then it's stored with the hash making it easy to grab the salt for use in your new application.  The dollar signs make it easy to parse each value.

```
algo, salt, hash = password_hash.split("$")
```

UPDATE: I pulled the below code from the web2py source but what you need to do is update the variable hmac_key with the value that you have set for auth.settings.hmac_key.  Hopefully when you run (after you update the hmac_key variable) this the hashes should match.

```
import hashlib
import hmac
from hashlib import sha512

h="sha512$b850ed44943b861b$c90901439983bce7fd512592b20d83f8e654632dee51de515773e70eabe609f62cebec64fed4df03acd54e6a627c9291e70fdf3a89996ffa796897c159e95c11"

algo,salt,hash = h.split("$")
print "crypted hash: %s"%hash

pwd = "pawan123"
##get this value from auth.settings.hmac_key
hmac_key = "" 

def get_digest(value):
    """
    Returns a hashlib digest algorithm from a string
    """
    if not isinstance(value, str):
        return value
    value = value.lower()
    if value == "md5":
        return md5
    elif value == "sha1":
        return sha1
    elif value == "sha224":
        return sha224
    elif value == "sha256":
        return sha256
    elif value == "sha384":
        return sha384
    elif value == "sha512":
        return sha512
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid digest algorithm: %s" % value)

#hashed = simple_hash(self.password, key, salt, digest_alg)
def simple_hash(text, key='', salt='', digest_alg='md5'):
    """
    Generates hash with the given text using the specified
    digest hashing algorithm
    """
    if not digest_alg:
        raise RuntimeError("simple_hash with digest_alg=None")
    elif not isinstance(digest_alg, str):  # manual approach
        h = digest_alg(text + key + salt)
    elif digest_alg.startswith('pbkdf2'):  # latest and coolest!
        iterations, keylen, alg = digest_alg[7:-1].split(',')
        return pbkdf2_hex(text, salt, int(iterations),
                          int(keylen), get_digest(alg))
    elif key:  # use hmac
        digest_alg = get_digest(digest_alg)
        h = hmac.new(key + salt, text, digest_alg)
    else:  # compatible with third party systems
        h = get_digest(digest_alg)()
        h.update(text + salt)
    return h.hexdigest()




print "result hash:  %s"%simple_hash(pwd, hmac_key, salt, "sha512")
```

Comment: But there is salt also for each password. How will we tackle that?

Comment: The "salt" in this case is the hmac_key + plain_text_user_password.  one of which you control (the secret hmac_key) and the other the user provides.  This makes the salt more secure by not storing it anywhere so password cracking will take much longer.

Comment: I updated my answer with some more information about the web2py salt

Comment: If you give me the full password hash (algo$salt$hash) from the web2py along with the plaintext I can help you write the Python

Comment: The plaintext is pawan123 and full password hash is : sha512$b850ed44943b861b$c90901439983bce7fd512592b20d83f8e654632dee51de515773e70eabe609f62cebec64fed4df03acd54e6a627c9291e70fdf3a89996ffa796897c159e95c11

Comment: which version of web2py are you using?

Comment: I updated the answer with a code snippet.  Just supply the correct value for hmac_key (you get that from the settings value auth.settings.hmac_key) and then see if the two hashes match up in the results.

Comment: The version is : Version 2.9.5-stable+timestamp.2014.03.16.02.35.39

Answer (score 0):

I think your best solution is to write an auth backend that will authenticate the User against the web2py base, then ask him to change or confirm his password and build a new Django auth-passwords.

The hole idea of crypto-hashing passwords is that you or any hacker can't see them if you have access to the database.

Here is the Django documentation on [writing an authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend).