# Import user passwords to Flask from web2py

Tags: python, flask

I'm developing an application in Flask. User authentication is done using Flask-User (with MySQL and SQLAlchemy). I want to import my users from a web2py application, where user passwords are encrypted with HMAC-SHA512. Is that possible or must I provide new passwords?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible. As seen here: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/api.html

The config variable USER_PASSWORD_HASH can be set to anything supplied by passlib, which should be PBKDF2! (assuming you're using PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA512).

There is more information here as to what is given to you with passlib: https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.html

If you are just using SHA, I would suggest using something like bcrypt and changing all passwords.

Comment: Another source for the solution: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088826/migrating-passwords-from-web2py-to-django)

Comment: Great post! Mark my answer as a solution if you think it deserves it ;)